# C++ send object trough socket

Tags: c++, sockets, object

I'm trying to build a client-server application. To accomplish it, I use socket.h and try to send my object. I know that it exist librairies which do the job for me but I would like to do it from my hand. I know that the problem are string because of the "ramdom" size. When the server receive my object, it create a seg fault when I'm trying to output/delete the object

```
#ifndef MESSAGE_HPP
#define MESSAGE_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <vector>

#include <fstream>

class Message
{
    int _from = -1; // id socket client
    int _to = -1;   //id socket friend
    std::string _format = "txt";
    std::string _message ="some message to send";
public:
    Message(int from, int to, std::string format, std::string message);
    Message() noexcept = default;
    ~Message(){}


    //OPERATOR
    friend std::ofstream& operator<<(std::ofstream& os, const Message& obj);
    friend std::ifstream& operator>>(std::ifstream& is, Message& obj);
};

//here start my cpp
Message::Message(int from, int to, std::string format, std::string message){
    _from = from;
    _to = to;
    _format = format;
    _message = message;
}



std::ofstream& operator<<(std::ofstream& os, const Message& obj)
{
    os << obj._from << " ";
    os << obj._to << " ";
    //os << obj._format.length();
    os << "\0"<< obj._format << " ";//my tries D;
    //os << obj._message.length();
    os << "\0" << obj._message;
    return os;
}
 
std::ifstream& operator>>(std::ifstream& is, Message& obj)
{
    char* tmp;
    size_t sizeOfString;
    
    is >> obj._from;
    is >> obj._to;
    is >> obj._format;
    is >> obj._message;
    is >> sizeOfString;
    /*tmp = new char[sizeOfString];
    is.get(tmp, sizeOfString+1);
    obj._format = tmp;
    delete[] tmp;
    tmp = NULL;
    
    is >> sizeOfString;
    tmp = new char[sizeOfString];
    is.get(tmp, sizeOfString+1);
    obj._message = tmp;
    delete[] tmp;
    tmp = NULL;*/

    return is;
}

#endif
```

As you can see. I already tried a lot of things found on internet. Send size of string and build with char[size], add a '\n', reinterpret_cast, etc.

The client do

```
std::string buffer;
    while (buffer != "END"){
        buffer.clear();
        std::cout << "You: ";
        std::getline( std::cin,buffer) ;
        Message mess = Message(1,2,"txt",buffer);
        //char* tmp = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&mess); // when I tried reinterpret_cast
        write(_connection_to_server_socket, &mess , sizeof(Message));
```

and server:

```
mes = new Message();
char buf[sizeof(Message)];//the try with reinterpret_cast
if ((valread = recv( sd , mes, sizeof(Message),0)) == 0) { 
                    //some code to manage client disconnection
                }
    else{
         std::cout << mes << std::endl; // seg fault
         //some code using the object
                }
    delete mes; //if segfault here if the std::cout is comment
```

Is it possible to show me a concrete example with number and std::string(with conversion to char*) using operator(or not if it impossible with operator<< and operator>>).
Thank you to the persons that will help me !
See you !

Comment: Sockets can only transmit **bytes**, not objects.  A pointer to memory, for example, would not likely have any meaning on a different process or a different computer.  Before sending an object, you must first decide how to convert the object into a series of bytes that are able to reproduce the object.  This process is often called **object serialization**.

Comment: I read about serialization but they always use librairies. The operator<< don't do the serielization ? it should convert my object into char[]. Or maybe, i misunderstood what the stream fonction produce as a result. It should work because when I send a simple char like in basic tutorial, it work. Or should I just create a std::string operator<<(socketid ,Message& mes) ? I'm a little bit lost, where should I start ?

Comment: `write(_connection_to_server_socket, &mess , sizeof(Message));` and `recv( sd , mes, sizeof(Message),0)) == 0)` copy byes from/to a `Message` object.  That object contains `std::string`s, and those strings contain pointers.  You don't need a library to serialize, you merely need to decide what bytes would describe your `Message`, regardless of what computer or process is looking at those bytes.  And you can name that function whatever you want.